# Некорректное отображение фона с использованием background-repeat-y;

Tags: css3, html5, вёрстка

Нужно разместить вертикальную линию на всю высоту страницы. Для этого я создала блок, которому задала определенную ширину, position: absolute, height:100%, фоном установила нужную картинку, и задала свойство background-repeat: repeat-y.

Картинка повторяется по оси y, но если присмотреться, то вертикальная линия как будто разделена на несколько частей и каждая из них смещена на несколько пикселей вправо в сравнение с верхней частью.

Comment: Это не ожидаемое поведение браузера, вам лучше предоставить минимальный код, необходимый для воспроизведения проблемы и если возможно скриншот, так будет легче понять в чем дело.

Comment: приложите ссылку на сайт, что ли.